# Binary tree pruning

Tags: c#, performance, language-agnostic, binary-tree

I have a generic binary tree which is used for calculating combinations of things - i.e. a powerset in set parlance.

Most of the time it is used for calculating subsets of size *N*.

As a real world example, say we have 10 players in a basketball squad and we want to calculate every starting 5.

In my particular problem domain, this is run millions of times so I'm trying to squeeze every bit of performance out of it that I can. Where I am only interested in subsets, I'm trying to prune the tree as I build it since it seems to be here where the bottleneck lies.

The tree is built from the leaves down so I guess I could count ancestors as I build and (in the example above) stop that branch whenever I have 5, but while this would work, I think it would probably add more overhead than it would save.

Any thoughts (aside from trying it)?

**EXAMPLE**

This data:

[image]

Yields this profile:

[image]

**AddGeneration** builds each level of the tree while **TraverseTree** pulls the results. As you can see there is something like a 99:1 split in terms of effort between the two.

Comment: I think you get more results depicting the problem with a concrete example, of the data gathered, when changed, what queried. As "binary tree" is more noise than shedding some light; it might not be the best data structure.

Comment: Did you made your homework and read the obvious literature - TAOCP, see http://www.kcats.org/csci/464/doc/knuth/fascicles/fasc3a.pdf ?

Comment: @DocBrown Do you have an English version?

Comment: How large are your input sets? If they are rather small (e.g. <= 64) but you need to perform many operations, than you can e.g. precompute integer sets and then only worry about mapping. Or treat your set as binary words for fast insert/remove/sum on sets. Depends on your input data, really.

Comment: @JoopEggen I've added some data for the example I outlined and provided a profile for the same.

Comment: The obvious indeed is the substitution of Powerset with an int/long and use helper function for manipulating the N bits accordingly. To have all sets of 3 one would need a N*(N-1)*(N-2) kind of loop (yielding N over 3), which is better than 2^N. Without real insight it is hard to help.

Comment: @RobbieDee: huh? The link I gave above is pointing to an English version.

Comment: @DocBrown Apologies, that may not have translated well. I meant *plain English*. My math is woeful...

Comment: @RobbieDee: even without understanding the whole math, it should not be too hard to implement algorithm L (page 4) or the tuned algorithm T (page 5).

Comment: Algorithm L is trivial to write if *N* is static but not sure about a general case...

Comment: Maybe look into [skip lists](http://shagie.net/2015/05/18/the-skip-list/)?

Comment: What does the binary tree have to do with the subsets? Is each node at level `i` a decision for whether to include element `i` or not? Do you need this tree for anything, or would a completely different generation process suit you just fine?

Comment: Yeah, each level of the tree is an element. It is used to create powersets but we just happen to use it to pull subsets rather than powersets most of the time. Aside from the speed issue there is space - it works fine for 10 elements but somewhere between 10-20 elements, we run out of memory. If the tree could be pruned somehow we may be able to raise the upper limit.

Comment: I don't understand, how exactly do you want to prune the tree? If you need the whole powerset, then there is nothing to prune.

Comment: @svick Yes, clearly it would only apply to subsets.

Comment: You still haven't answered the question of whether you need the tree for anything. If memory pressure is a problem then it seems natural to throw the tree away entirely and write a method which gives you an `IEnumerable<ISet<T>>` using memory proportional to the number of items in the original set.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Memory pressure isn't a problem - it comfortably handles as many elements as we currently need it to. Performance isn't a huge issue either, it runs within an acceptable amount of time, and when it doesn't, we can cache the known subsets. What does seem sub-optimal is that the entire tree is built whether it is required or not - hence the pruning question. Whilst I am interested in different ways of achieving the same, the solution we have is proven and widely used so there would be zero benefit in revisiting it as things currently stand.